# How do I convert a hexstring to hex?

Tags: python, type-conversion

If I have a string with the following value:

```
STR = "00DE"
```

how do I convert that so that `STR` becomes `0x00DE`? What function do I use?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want STR to be a string in the form you describe, the simplest way is to  prepend `'0x'` to the string:

```
STR = '0x' + STR
```

If you mean that you want STR to become an integer with the indicated numeric value, then invoke the `int()` constructor:

```
STR = int(STR, 16)
```

Comment: Through expirementing I noticed that if you convert the string to int like this:

STR= int(STR,16) and the convert that to hex you will get the hex value you want.

Thank you so much for answering though.